# how do I create a UserForm in VBA (Word) with code

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to program the user form in VBA, so that I can simply pass on the macro and it works for these people. I have read and tried a lot on the internet but there was an error with all solutions. The errors were different depending on the code. Thanks in advance for the help.
The macro is for Word.

My Code:

```
    Dim UserForm1 As Object

Set UserForm1 = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)

With UserForm1
    .With = 400
    .Height = 300
End With
```

Comment: The code you posted could never work in Word - the 'ThisWorkbook' reference belongs to Excel, not Word. Moreover, no such code will run on any system which has not had trusted access given to the VBA project model. This is a dangerous thing to set as the default state. Hence it is most unlikely you'll be able to «simply pass on the macro and it works for these people».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change the macro setting. and then, you need make small adjustment in your code.

**Step 1:** Enable VBA project access

```
Open your workbook
Go to File > Options > Trust Center
Click on Trust Center Settings... 
Under Macro Settings, make sure Trust access to the VBA project object model is checked.
```

**Step 2:** Dont assign width and height directly, instead use .properties

```
Sub test()

Dim UserForm1 As Object

Set UserForm1 = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)

With UserForm1
    .Properties("Caption") = "New Form"
    .Properties("Width") = 300
    .Properties("Height") = 270
End With

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** Above code will work only in Excel. For word document remove the line `Set UserForm1 = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)` and add `Set UserForm1 = ActiveDocument.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)`

Comment: If I add this now, I get an error with the content "Compilation error: Variable not defined" and refers to "ThisWorkbook".

Comment: Edited my answer to work in word. Please check the EDIT section.